# Doctrine changing ID of injected data

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, audit-trail

I have some injected data to get Doctrine started.

My Member (user) table looks something like

```
id | first_name | last_name | email | password ...
```

Data injected as follows:

```
INSERT INTO member (id, first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES (1, "Default", "System", "default@system.com", "system_pass")
```

Running `$defaultMember = $repository->findOneBy(array("first_name" => "Default"))`
yields a Member object, and `_em->contains($defaultMember)` is true.  The object even shows ID of 1 in the debugger.  Yet when I make a change: `$defaultMember->setFirstName("Default2")` and flush back to the database, it tries to insert a new (duplicate) member, with whatever the next id in the sequence is.

Comment: Without the code that makes these *changes*, it's impossible to provide any advice.

Comment: I added the code that makes the change.  The name is not a part of any key or index.

Comment: That's nowhere near enough code. We need to see the whole lot from getting the repo to the flush operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved with a combination of getter/setter for the id (not sure if this was the underlying problem), and using $this->_em in the repository as opposed to $this->getEntityManager().

Answer (score 0):

I have got similar issue with inserting new record instead of updating existing record. My issue was caused by `$entity2 = clone $entity1`. After that I updated `$entity2->name = $newName` then try saving it (persist() then flush()). I expected it will update existing record as id is given. But no, it inserted a new record.

After tracing code with xdebug, I found out that each object will be indexed by `spl_object_hash($object)` which will return unique id for `$object`. If the id is not the same as the one got indexed, SF2 will try to insert a new record.

I don't know if you tried persisting a cloned object or not but I guess the reason is the same with mine. Try to investigate in that way, you can make it work as you want. Otherwise, post more code then people can help you easier.